# VBA userform: Calculate timezone based on whether date entered is daylight savings or not

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a spreadsheet into which will be entered a number of events, such as communications sent. I would like to create a userform into which a user can enter 1. the Date of the event 2. the time (in EST) at which the event occurred 2. the equivalent UTC time for that event 3. the equivalent Tokyo time for that event.

A date is always available to be entered, but you never know if the time stamp for a given event is going to be an EST, UTC or Tokyo time stamp. I would like it so that the three texboxes for UTC, EST or Tokyo are automatically populated if any one of them has a time value. So for example if time stamp is entered in the EST box, VBA will add 4 hours and populate the UTC box and add another 12 or whatever to populate the Tokyo box.

To start with, I wrote the following code for the Date textbox in the userform:

```
Public Sub dtefrm_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim dte
Dim dstdte As Boolean


Let dte = CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value)


Select Case True
    Case dte > CDate("3/9/2008") And dte < CDate("11/2/2008")
        dstdte = True
        Me.dayconf.Value = "Daylight Savings"

    End Select


End Sub
```

Now, I would like to attach code to the EST text box so that when time is entered into it, the UTC text box is populated with that time + 4 if the Date is between 3/1/2008 and 11/1/2008, and + 5 if it is not.

This is what I came up with:

```
Public Sub estfrm_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

varest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Me.estfrm.Value, "hh:mm:ss")
Me.estfrm.Value = varest
Let dte = CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value)

Select Case True
    Case dte > CDate("3/9/2008") And dte < CDate("11/2/2008")
        dstdte = True
    End Select


If dstdte = True Then
    Me.utcfrm.Value = CDate(Me.utcfrm.Value) + 4
End If


End Sub
```

I think I was having trouble using the dstdte Boolean value in the EST box code, I tried to make both the subs public that didn't help so I copied the select case code from the first sub to the second, but still no luck. Right now I'm getting Error thirteen. I tried 4/24 instead of 4, same issue.

for reference, dtefrm is the name of the text box into which the user enters the date, dayconf is a textbox on the form that just says Daylight savings if the date matches and estfrm is the name of the box into which EST time is entered and utcfrm is the name of the UTC box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a function you can call from both:

```
Function IsDts(ByVal cellValueDate as Date)
    Select Case True
        Case cellValueDate > CDate("3/9/2008") And cellValueDate < CDate("11/2/2008")
            IsDts = True
        Case Else
            IsDts = False
    End Select
End Function
```

And call this in your other events like estfrm_BeforeUpdate

```
isValDst = IsDts(CDate(Me.dtefrm.Value))
```

Comment: note that i recommended a diff solution that involved using a .NET com callable wrapper to detect dst, in case anyone comments

Comment: I was trying to set up exactly this kind of function but was failing miserably lol. I guess I had a number of syntax errors; also I'm not entirely clear on the relationship between functions and textbos subroutines and how to link them. I was leaving out "ByVal" lol but this works beautifully thank you ever so much good sir. 

BTW, Citizen Kane is one my favorite movies of all time. If you haven't already, watch "The Trial" by Orson Welles. Based on a Kafka short story. Will blow your mind!